# create virtual table, view, using sails-mysql adapter in codeship

Tags: sails.js, codeship

I use codeship for build my app with following config file. everything is fine before I use one controller to retrieve data from a view "virtual table". From my local, the code is fine. but during codeship build process, error report that `Table 'test.testview' doesn't exist`. any way I can use sails-mysql adapter to create the virtal table in codeship build process?

```
module.exports.connections = {
    codeshipDb: {
      adapter: 'sails-mysql',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'test',
      database: 'test'
    },
 }
```

Comment: Have you already created the view in the codeship mysql DB?

Comment: no, how can i do it?

Comment: Should be the same way you created it locally -- connect to the DB using the Codeship MySQL configuration host, user, password, and database, then create the view.